# All of my h1s keep bunching up together in the middle of page

Tags: html, css

Making a one page website with the nav jumping to different sections using #. After three sections all of my headings (`h1`) bunch up as one and I can't seem to make it change.

This is my grid:

```
.full-width {
    width: 1140px;
    height: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.half-width {
    width: 1210px;
    float: left;
}

.third-width {
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
}
```

This is one of the headings bunching up:

HTML:

```
<section id="registry">
    <div class="full-width">
        <h1> We have registries at these stores: </h1>
        <div class="half-width">
            <p> David Jones </p>
            <p> Myer </p>
            <p> Super Amart </p>
            <p> The Good Guys </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#registry h1 {
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 30px 0;
    float: center;
}

#registry p {
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    font-size: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 30px 50px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean bunching up? Looks OK to me. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWpNqB

Comment: Just noticed you're a new user. Welcome to SO. Be sure you give us a [mcve] that actually illustrates your problem.

Comment: in the css for h1 you have float: center; that is not an option. you can use text-align : center;

Comment: Would you want a screenshot of it?

Comment: read this to see how to center https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: All of my stuff is centered fine, they just all are in the one spot but I want them on top of each individual section

Comment: Please give us an actual example that shows things going wrong. Also, probably a stupid question, but is `half-width` supposed to be wider than `full-width`?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and is working fine, also did a bit of experimentation.
Check the code pen I created to test, I don't think the h1s are "bunching up".

```
<section id="registry">
    <div class="full-width">
        <h1> We have registries at these stores: </h1>
      <h1> We have registries at these stores: </h1>


        <div class="half-width">
            <h1> We have registries at these stores: </h1>
            <p> David Jones </p>
            <p> Myer </p>
            <p> Super Amart </p>
            <p> The Good Guys </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="full-width">
        <h1> We have registries at these stores: </h1>
      <h1> We have registries at these stores: </h1>
      <h1> We have registries at these stores: </h1>
        <div class="half-width">
            <p> David Jones </p>
            <p> Myer </p>
            <p> Super Amart </p>
            <p> The Good Guys </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

http://codepen.io/adrianrios/pen/xqYZrG